# ros-electric package

Tags: ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I am new to ros and using husky.But there is no package for the Husky in ubuntu 11.10.
can anybody tell me where would i find the ros-electric package of husky for Ubuntu 11.10(oneric).

thanks,
Kunal Ganeshe
Student MSc Robotics and Embedded systems
University of Salford
Greater Manchester

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30568/ros-electric-package/) by [kunalrex](https://answers.ros.org/users/2061/kunalrex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunalrex](https://answers.ros.org/users/2061/kunalrex/) on 2012-04-23**:
thanks tfoote for you answer and i got the husky package and it is working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The electric husky package appears to be in all repos. http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0